# R: How to make second level indented bullet points using RMarkdown ioslides?

Tags: r, r-markdown

How do I make second level bullets in RMarkdown from Rstudio?

I tried

```
* Level1
  + leve2
```

and it didn't work. It's not exactly clear how to do it from the tutorial. This seems so simple to do in normal RMarkdown.

Comment: saying it didnt work and providing two lines of code is not helpful

Comment: [seems 4 spaces is the key](http://www.macdrifter.com/2012/04/writing-in-markdown-lists.html) (or **two** tabs for me in Rstudio)

Comment: You have to make sure the full list is recognized as a bulleted list by inserting a blank line before the first bullet *and* you have to have 4 spaces before the '+' character for this to work.

Answer (score 22):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
date: "Friday, October 31, 2014"
output: pdf_document
---


```{r}
summary(cars)
```


1. Item 1
2. Item 2
    a. Item 2a
    b. Item 2b
````

Look at the above one, maybe the spacing is the problem

Comment: With Rpres, it was sufficient to indent second-level list by two spaces, conveniently lining up with the text of the first-level items. But when the output is produced by Pandoc (e.g., for Beamer or ioslides documents), you have to indent by four spaces.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Is also older than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866916/incremental-nested-lists-in-rmarkdown) question, but is essentially the same, despite being about Rmarkdown.

Answer (score 14):

- Level 1

  - Level 2 (four spaces)

This works for me.

Answer (score 4):

The OP asked about ioslides, so:

Although it isn't detailed in the [ioslides guide](https://garrettgman.github.io/rmarkdown/ioslides_presentation_format.html#overview), the comment by @user20650 is correct: When using ioslides, simply ensure you use four spaces or one tab for the second level, e.g.:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide Header

- Level 1
    - Level 2
```

Note, you *could* also use basic html to kludge it:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide Header

<ul>
<li>Level 1
    <ul>
    <li>Level 2</li>
</li>
</ul>
```

Subsequent levels simply require more spaces added before the bullet:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide Header

- Level 1
    - Level 2
        - Level 3
```