# Incremental sub-bullets in RMarkdown and Beamer

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer

I write slides in RMarkdown and compile them into Beamer presentations.  I want to incrementally reveal bullets and subbullets on slides.  Below is a `.Rmd` file showing some of my failed attempts.  In these attempts, I insert 4 spaces before  the subbullet lines.  I want to control the incrementing on a slide-by-slide (or even list-by-list) basis.

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "RTM"
output: beamer_presentation
---

## This works, incremental bullets

>- Bullet 1
>- Bullet 2

## This nests, but does not increment

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
    + subbullet 1
    + subbullet 2

## This increments, but fails to nest

>- Bullet 1
>- Bullet 2
>    - subbullet 1
>    - subbullet 2

## This increments, but fails to nest

>- Bullet 1
>- Bullet 2
>    + subbullet 1
>    + subbullet 2

## This increments, but fails to nest

>- Bullet 1
>- Bullet 2
    + subbullet 1
    + subbullet 2

## This increments, but fails to nest and ignores subbullet status

>- Bullet 1
>- Bullet 2
    >+ subbullet 1
    >+ subbullet 2
```

Comment: which is your `pandoc` version?

Comment: it works for me with `pandoc 2.0.5`.

Comment: @romles I am using `pandoc` version 1.19.2.1, bundled with the current version of RStudio.

When you say "it works" for you, which of my snippets above renders correctly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: (That's RStudio version 1.1.442.)

Comment: the first two *but fails to nest*

Comment: Thanks, @romles.  This works using `pandoc 2.1.3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is solved by updating `pandoc`.  This works using `pandoc 2.1.3`

I updated my `pandoc` at the Terminal with `brew install pandoc`, which threw an error suggesting I run `brew link --overwrite pandoc`.  I did so, and my pandoc version was updated.  I recompile the `.Rmd` file and the first two *but fails to nest* cases increment and nest.

Answer (score 0):

Kumar's answer at [Incremental nested lists in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36866916/incremental-nested-lists-in-rmarkdown) is useful and shows how to increment and nest by adding an extra space at the bullet level.

I am not sure how to create slides where the nested bullets appear at the same time as the bullet under which they are nested.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).